# What does "instantiating a pack expansion" mean?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, parameter-pack

I get confused when I encounter this sentence (**bold**) from the standard - [[temp.deduct]/11:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#11)

> [ Note: Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>
> - (11.1)
>   **Attempting to instantiate a pack expansion** containing multiple packs
>   of differing lengths.
> - [..]

It's known that "*instantiation*" is a process of creating an instance of a class or template. So a pack expansion is not a template or class to instantiate an instance from.

My question is what does "instantiating a pack expansion" mean? Is it mean "expanding" pack expansion?

And how I can instantiate a pack expansion?

Comment: Try reading it, in context, using the meaning "instantiating a template whose body contains a pack expansion".  But the latter "multiple packs of different lengths" must be inside a single expansion, when the containing template is instantiated, and not merely in a template containing multiple independent expansions.

Comment: @BenVoigt - It is referred also to in [temp.variadic]/5: _"A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, **the instantiation of which** produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list [...] "_

Comment: @BenVoigt - ...and in [temp.variadic]/8: "_**The instantiation of a pack expansion** considers items [...]_"

Comment: It's just the principle that instantiating a thing (template) that has a body structure containing many smaller things (statements, expressions, pack expansions) you end up with an instance of every component inside the body structure.  So you might say all those components of the body have also been instantiated.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#18 defines pack expansion in another context

Comment: @John https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.variadic#8 link for your quote

Comment: @BenVoigt - "_Try reading it, in context, using the meaning "instantiating a template whose body contains a pack expansion"._" - Interesting. Suppose you have a function template `g` takes two type parameters, and you have the following: `template <class...Ts, class...Us> 
auto f() -> decltype((g<Ts, Us>(), ...)); ` Then your wording is not applied: the pack expansion is in the function type of `f` not in its body.

Comment: @BenVoigt - So if I take your rule as "instantiating a pack expansion" means "_instantiating a template whose body or function type (since pack expansion cannot appear as a default argument of another pack) contains a pack expansion_", this would still be correct?